# tmux consuming 100% of cpu

Tags: tmux, byobu

I've been running `byobu` for a while now, and in the last few hours it has started to consume 30-100% of the CPU on the core it's running on. This a noticeable delay when entering text, or switching windows.

It does not appear to be an issue with the server (i've included the output of `top` below). Total memory and cpu usage appears fine, and if I open a new `byobu` session on the server it works fine (consuming almost 0% of the CPU).

I've never experienced this before. Any advice on what is causing it, and how to fix it without killing the whole session would be appreciated!

```
top - 16:09:40 up 93 days,  1:59,  4 users,  load average: 42.87, 42.77, 42.78
Tasks: 792 total,  48 running, 656 sleeping,   0 stopped,  88 zombie
Cpu(s): 38.3%us, 22.4%sy,  0.0%ni, 39.2%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  528381020k total, 514696248k used, 13684772k free,    13172k buffers
Swap: 536855548k total, 114819772k used, 422035776k free,   501060k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                                                                                       
66004 scottr-u  20   0 88932  23m  888 S   52  0.0 270:36.19 tmux
```

Comment: Do you see the same behaviour just running tmux?

Comment: I don't even see the same behaviour if I run another `byobu` session. It doesn't seem like a replicable problem.

Comment: That makes it a very difficult problem to troubleshoot...

Comment: Yeah I'm not expecting much. I didn't see anything on google, so I'm just hoping someone else has seen this before and had more insight as to what was going on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible that there's a runaway status script from [Byobu](http://byobu.co) that's consuming all of the CPU.  You can perhaps disable them one by one until you find the culprit.  The updates_available script is probably the most resource intensive, and the one that causes this sort of trouble most often.  If you do find which one is misbehaving, please file a bug at https://bugs.launchpad.net/byobu.

*Full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*

Comment: After logging back in this morning it seems to be behaving, CPU usage at <10%. If I see it happen again I'll try disabling some status notifications!

Comment: Wouldn't it be a good idea to find out what version of Byobu @Manetheran is running, especially since there are known bugs (like https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/byobu/+bug/1010505 ) that can cause this issue?

Comment: Byobu version: 5.17
Tmux version: 1.6

I haven't had the issue replicate since (still the same byobu session open).